# Selenium Javascript - Access webelements within iframe programatically

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, iframe

I am trying to access web elements within iFrame programatically. Using below method to check the same

- Compare the URL of elements with the base URI
- If its same then web element is in main DOM otherwise its in iFrame
- Use switchTo.frame() to switch to iFrame and perform actions

In above method, the following methods used to get URI of element

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].baseURI;
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("w3-btn w3-border")[0].baseURI
```

**Queries:**

1. Is there any function or method to get baseURI using xpath? I don't want to use Tagname or classname.
2. Also, how to achieve same when multiple iFrames or iFrame inside another iFrame.
3. **Kindly suggest if any other method**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will help in switch iframes automatically....
This code handles 2 level iframes i.e.

iframe -1                            -------> Level 1  
iframe - 2                           -------> Level 1  
----  child iframe - 1 [under iframe 2 ]   -------> Level 2  
iframe - 3                            -------> Level 1

Code

```
async function switchtoiframe(wdriver, xpath) {
  //console.log(" ---- Code to switch iframes start ---- ");

  wdriver.switchTo().defaultContent();

  let parentEleFound = false;   
  let childEleFound = false;
  let parentframeId;
  let childframeId;
  
  // find number iframes in main content
  await wdriver.findElements(By.tagName('iframe')).then(async function (pIframe) {
      console.log("Total iframe count - " + pIframe.length);
      
      // if number of iframes found then switch to iframe
      if (pIframe.length > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i<pIframe.length; i++)
          {              
              await wdriver.switchTo().frame(i);   // switch to parent iframe
              
              // find number of child iframes in parent frame
              await wdriver.findElements(By.tagName('iframe')).then(async function (cIframe) {
                  //console.log("total child iframe count - " + cIframe.length + " in parent frame " + i);
                  
                  // if number of iframes found then switch to child iframe
                  if (cIframe.length > 0) {
                      for (let j = 0; j<cIframe.length; j++)
                      {                          
                          await wdriver.switchTo().frame(j);  // switch to child iframe
                            
                          // check whether element is available in child iframe
                          await wdriver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).then(async function (cElement) 
                          {                              
                              console.log("child for loop : j - "+ j);
                              console.log("child element - "+ cElement.length);
                              if(cElement.length == 1)
                              {
                                  childframeId = j;
                                  childEleFound = true;
                              }                              
                              
                              // switch back to parent iframe
                              wdriver.switchTo().parentFrame(i);
                          });
  
                          console.log("Element found in child iframe - "+ childEleFound)
                          if (childEleFound == true ){  
                              // switch to child iframe where element is found
                              await wdriver.switchTo().frame(childframeId)
                              break; // break for loop [j]
                          }
                      }
                  } 
              });
              if (childEleFound == true ){  // if element found in child iframe then break the parent for loop [i] also.
                  break;
              }
  
              // if no child iframes then find element in parent iframe
              await wdriver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).then(async function (pElement) 
              {
                  console.log("parent for loop : i - "+ i);
                  console.log("parent element - "+ pElement.length);
                  if(pElement.length == 1)
                  {
                      parentframeId = i;
                      parentEleFound = true;
                  }
                  
                  // switch back to main content
                  wdriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
              });
  
              console.log("Element found in parent iframe - "+ parentEleFound)
              if (parentEleFound == true ){  
                  
                  // switch to iframe where element is found                        
                  await wdriver.switchTo().frame(parentframeId)
                  break;
              } 
          }
      } 
  });
  
  console.log(" ---- Code to switch iframes end ---- ");
}
```